# Mongodb not working properly : Socket already in use?

Tags: mongodb

I am taking the mongodb university class and having problems getting mongod to work properly.  I have been trying for hours to try to get it to work properly, but I keep getting the same error.

When I try to run mongod I am getting this error:

erics-mbp:~ emlandst$ mongod --dbpath data
2015-08-16T18:55:24.186-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017

2015-08-16T18:55:24.186-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use

2015-08-16T18:55:24.186-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory data not found., terminating

2015-08-16T18:55:24.186-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

If I am correct the server is set to run on port 27017 by default and for some reason it is being blocked.  I tried the ps waux | grep mongo and then I killed the instance, but still i get the same error.

I am trying to just delete everything so I can start all over, but I have no idea how to do that.  I'm sure it is simple I just don't have a lot of experience.  Thank you

Comment: Suggest you discuss this with your teacher or professor.

Comment: Please note that killing a process won't immediately set the port free, it may take a while before the port is released due to timeout.  You can check if that's the case running this command "netstat -alp | grep 27017'

Comment: Ok I will give it some time I never considered that. @richard chambers I have, but I am not even sure If i am asking the right questions to solve this problem.  I am basically just guessing the problem because im not really sure whats going on.